# How to add power on sound in bootanimation and I want to play the some sound effects while android booting time

Tags: android, animation, android-source

I have created the custom bootanimation.zip file with PNG files in the custom aosp build was working fine. so now i want to add poweron sound for the device startup time. it means when the bootanimations comes to screen at the same time need to play the poweron sound . i have added poweron.ogg file path as /system/media/audio/ui/poweron.ogg. bootanimation.zip also i have replaced in the /system/media/ location.

Answer (score 0):

The system selects audio file from the animation zipfile (bootanimation.zip).

Here is the link which has complete explanation on bootanimation format:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/bootanimation/FORMAT.md#bootanimation-format

Comment: i have followed the same steps & format in my bootanimation.zip.

Comment: Have you included audio file as a part of bootanimation.zip file?

Comment: yes i have included the audio file. firstime tried with poweron.wav & second time i have tried the poweron.ogg. But it not worked

Comment: Rename audio file name from poweron.wav to audio.wav and then try.

Comment: Well, I have been trying with audio.wav placed inside "part*" directories in bootanimation.zip. Icould see the animation but not the audio. Why though?